# Save information to the second page and so on

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have this code in my php email body.

```
<p><a href="http://indd.jncy.com/get-referal.php?member_name='.$member_name.'&member_email='.$member_email.'">Register</a></p>
```

In the link of the code above, when it is clicked it will direct the user to the get-referal.php.

Here is the code in the get-refereal.php:

```
    <?php 

        $referal_name=$_GET[member_name];
        $referal_email=$_GET[member_email];

    ?>

    <body>

    <?php echo $referal_name ?>
    <?php echo $referal_email ?>

    <a href="home.php">Home</a>
    <a href="galery.php">Galery</a>

    </body>
```

In the get-referal.php I am able to get the `referal_name` and the `referal_email`

But what I want know is when the user click `Home.php` or `Galery.php`, I am still able to get the `referal_name` and the `referal_email`without have to set the link to

---

`'php?member_name='.$member_name.'&member_email='.$member_email.'`

---

**[UPDATE]**

What I want now is how to hide the member_name and member_email in the url link so that the user can't change it?

Comment: Use sessions. Look it up in the manual.

Comment: Now you can use `$_SESSION` variable to hide member data.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the values in session variables.

At the start of each page where you need the session to persist put:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Then in the page where you grab the GET data, store it in a session var:

```
$_SESSION['member_name'] = $_GET['member_name'];
$_SESSION['member_email'] = $_GET['member_email'];
```

You will,then be able to retrieve from the SESSION super global on any page with a valid session running.

I would be very careful in how you use the data from the $_GET global as it's very easily tampered with.

Comment: How to make it safe from _easily tempered with_?

Comment: dont use a $_GET global as its easy for someone to substitute the data in it. Or if you have to, pass it through a sanitisation function.  If you like my posted answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<p><a href="http://indd.jncy.com/get-referal.php?member_name=<?PHP echo $member_name; ?>&member_email=<?PHP echo $member_email;?>">Register</a></p>
```

User `<?PHP ?>` for use php variables.

**[UPDATE]**

Store `$member_name` and `$member_email` to Session.

First start session then use it.

```
<?PHP
session_start();

$_SESSION['referal_name']=$member_name;
$_SESSION['referal_email']=$member_email;
?>
<p><a href="http://indd.jncy.com/get-referal.php">Register</a></p>
```

Now write following code in `get-referal.php`

```
<?PHP
session_start();

$referal_name=$_SESSION['referal_name'];
$referal_email=$_SESSION['referal_email'];

?>
<body>

<?php echo $referal_name; ?>
<?php echo $referal_email; ?>

<a href="home.php">Home</a>
<a href="galery.php">Galery</a>

</body>
```

Comment: I have also a session for login user. The session for login user is different from the session for referral user. However, when I click the link directly for the referral user, it reads the session for the login user instead for the referral.

Answer (score 1):

start session at each page

```
<?php
        // Start the session
        session_start();
 ?>
```

At page get-refereal.php

```
$_SESSION['referal_name']=$referal_name;
$_SESSION['referal_email']=$referal_email;
```

At pagehome.php and galery.php  you can get it by

```
$val1=$_SESSION['referal_name']; and $val2=$_SESSION['referal_email']; 

echo $val1;
echo $val2;
```